# Does mediaelement.js wordpress version support subtitle?

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js

I am using wordpress 3.7.1 and use buildin mediaelements.js video support.
I want to ask does this version support subtitles?

I have a video in this page with subtitles

http://www.enterpr1se.info/2013/06/gordon-music-station-onslaught-of-locusts/

Here is the code

```
[video width="1920" height="1080" mp4="http://www.enterpr1se.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Locust-attack.mp4" captions="http://www.enterpr1se.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Locust_attack_jap.srt" captions="http://www.enterpr1se.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Locust_attack_eng.srt"][/video]
```

But there's no control for captions.

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress implementation of MediaElement.js includes support for subtitles, but doesn't provide any method for actually using them.

There's a plug-in that gives you a library-based control to use subtitles:

[Accessible Video Library](http://wordpress.org/plugins/accessible-video-library/), or you can write a custom filter to add support. There's no filter available on the track elements within the video output, so you just have to do some straight-up search and replace. It's kind of ugly.

Basically, you'd have to write a custom shortcode wrapping the video shortcode, and after producing the Video shortcode HTML, insert a track element with your subtitles.